# pass multiple nested templated class to templated functions

Tags: c++, templates

I have been at this for hours but can't seem to be able to find a way to solve this. Before you ask, this is not a homework question.

So here goes, I have two custom templated classes called `Matrix<T>` and `Vector<T>`, and I have this function called `train(...)` which takes in a `std::vector<VectorT<T>*>&` called `X` and a `std::vector<Matrix<T>*>&` called `Generators` along with a few other templated params. This function is described below:

```
template <typename Mat, typename Vec>
void train (vector<Mat*>& Generators,
            const vector<Vec*>& X,
            Vec* root_node, // This is assuming that the root node is in X
            int n,
            int q)
{
    // Create a schreier tree out of the generating set and the input set
    tuple<std::unordered_map<int, tuple<int, Mat*>>, size_t>
    tree_info_ = FiniteField::ComputeSchreierTree(Generators, X, root_node, n, q);

    std::unordered_map<int, tuple<int, Mat*>> tree_ = std::get<0>(tree_info_);

    make_move(1, 1280, tree_, Generators, n, q);
}
```

Where `Mat` is `Matrix<T>`, and `Vec` is `Vector<T>`. The above function takes in these parameters and generates a `std::unordered_map<_key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>` called `tree_` where key is an `int` and value is `std::tuple<_Elements ...>` of `int` and a `Mat*`.

Now what I want to do here is pass this `tree_` and `Generators` to another function called `make_move(...)`, defined below:

```
    template <typename Mat,
                typename I,
                typename... Args,
                template <typename, typename, typename...> class Tup,
                template <typename, typename, typename...> class Tree,
                template <typename, typename...> class X>
    void make_move(I i, I j,
                    Tree<I, Tup<I, Mat*, Args...>, Args...>& tree_,
                    X<Mat*, Args...>& Generators, int n, int q) {
        // Make a direct edge between node i and node j
        // by first tracing the path from node j to
        // node i, multiplying all the edge labels along
        // the way and then taking the inverse.

//      // Note: node j is in a deeper level of the tree than node i
        Mat M(n, n);
        M.identity();


        while (std::get<0>(tree_[j]) != std::get<0>(tree_[i])) {
            FiniteField::dot(M, *std::get<1>(tree_[j]), M, q);
            j = std::get<0>(tree_[j]);
        }


        M.print();
    }
```

The problem here is when I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
error: no instance of function template "make_move" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (int, int, std::unordered_map<int, std::tuple<int, Matrix<unsigned int> *>, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::tuple<int, Matrix<unsigned int> *>>>>, std::vector<Matrix<unsigned int> *, std::allocator<Matrix<unsigned int> *>>, int, int)
```

This is my first experience passing multiple nested templated class to templated functions, therefore I am not aware of the correct keyword combinations to search for in google, which is why I have not been able to get far on this, threfore any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should add std:: to your unordered_map and tuple, non ?

Comment: I have these at the beginning using std::unordered_map;
using std::vector;
using std::tuple;

Answer (score 0):

In

```
template <typename Mat, typename Vec>
void make_move(int i, int j,
               unordered_map<int, tuple<int, Mat*>>& tree_,
               vector<Mat*>& Generators, int n, int q);
```

`Vec` cannot be deduced (it is not listed in arguments), so you have to specify it at call:

```
make_move<Mat, Vec>(1, 1280, tree_, Generators, n, q);
```

But there is probably a typo:

- Should `vector<Mat*>` be `Vec` instead ?
- Should `make_move` have `Vec` template argument ?

Comment: Hi, my apologies, I did make a typo, but I have changed the make_move code, and I believe this reflects more towards what I am actually aiming for.

Comment: Now issue is that `Args...` should be identical `Tree<I, Tup<I, Mat*, Args...>, Args...>& tree_,
                    X<Mat*, Args...>&` which is not your case.